# Regex Pattern to fetch the text between the tags

Tags: php, regex

my string is:

```
$p['message'] = '[name]Fozia Faizan[/name]\n[cell]03334567897[/cell]\n[city]Karachi, Pakistan[/city]';
```

What I want to do is to use REGEX pattern so as to get the result like this:

```
    Name: Fozia Faizan
    Cell #: 03334567897
    City: Karachi, Pakistan
```

I've tried this regex:

```
    $regex = "/\\[(.*?)\\](.*?)\\[\\/\\1\\]/";
    $message = preg_match_all($regex, $p['message'], $matches);
```

but it didn't work at all. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, using the great reply from @jh314, you could write:

```
$p['message'] = '[name]Fozia Faizan[/name]\n[cell]03334567897[/cell]\n[city]Karachi, Pakistan[/city]';
$m = array();
preg_match_all('|\[(.*?)](.*?)\[/\1]|', $p['message'], $m);
$result = @array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
$out = "Name: {$result['name']}\nCell #: {$result['cell']}\nCity: {$result['city']}";
echo $out;
//$outHTML = nl2br("Name: {$result['name']}\nCell #: {$result['cell']}\nCity: {$result['city']}");
//echo $outHTML;
```

That will give you:

```
Name: Fozia Faizan
Cell #: 03334567897
City: Karachi, Pakistan
```

**EDIT**: You could also add `@` just before the name of the function like so: `@array_combine`, to suppress error at top of your page, only if this does work and you get the results as expected.

Comment: Thanks but it shows this error on the top of my php page: `array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have at least 1 element`

How to resolve this?

Comment: I've updated the code. Could you try again? Is your $p[message] value the same as what you posted on top? Or is it different text value?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, your answer has helped me. Thanks for all others

Answer (score 1):

Your regex already works, just combine the result in `$matches`:

```
$p['message'] = '[name]Fozia Faizan[/name]\n[cell]03334567897[/cell]\n[city]Karachi, Pakistan[/city]';
$regex = "/\\[(.*?)\\](.*?)\\[\\/\\1\\]/";
preg_match_all('~\[(.*?)](.*?)\[/\1]~', $p['message'], $matches);
$result = array_combine ($matches[1], $matches[2]);
print_r($result);
```

will give you:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Fozia Faizan
    [cell] => 03334567897
    [city] => Karachi, Pakistan
)
```

Comment: Sorry for such a noob question but how to manipulate this array? I mean I used your code but get blank spaces. Can you please show me how to use an array to get the result? I'm sorry I am new to php :/